# Apply Multiplication on many intervals on a single table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql-9.1

My data consists of 1024 rows and 2 columns.Its structure looks like

> [image]

I want to select three intervals from a single table based on first column. In that selected intervals second column values should be multiplied by values

```
SELECT * FROM del 
   WHERE wavelength BETWEEN 341 AND 348 
         OR wavelength BETWEEN 551 AND 664  
         OR wavelength BETWEEN 998 AND 1021
```

In this one, intervals are selected using this query and

- first interval second column values is multiplied by 0.25
- second interval second column multiplied by 0.5
- third interval second column should be multiplied by 0.25.

After multiplication i want to display the wavelength and multiplied reflectance values in second column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the first and third range is to be multiplied by `0.25` and the second by `0.5`

you can use the below query.

```
SELECT wavelength, 
       ( reflect * 0.25 ) AS reflect 
FROM   wavelength 
WHERE  ( wavelength BETWEEN 341 AND 348 ) 
        OR ( wavelength BETWEEN 998 AND 1021 ) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT wavelength, 
       ( reflect * 0.5 ) AS reflect 
FROM   wavelength 
WHERE  wavelength BETWEEN 551 AND 664;
```

if all three are to be multiplied by different values you can use

```
SELECT wavelength, 
       ( reflect * 0.25 ) AS reflect 
FROM   wavelength 
WHERE  wavelength BETWEEN 341 AND 348 
       OR wavelength BETWEEN 998 AND 1021 
UNION ALL 
SELECT wavelength, 
       ( reflect * 0.5 ) AS reflect 
FROM   wavelength 
WHERE  wavelength BETWEEN 551 AND 664 
UNION ALL 
SELECT wavelength, 
       ( reflect * 0.25 ) AS reflect 
FROM   wavelength 
WHERE  wavelength BETWEEN 998 AND 1021
```

demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c41b/10

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT wavelength, 
       CASE WHEN wavelength BETWEEN 551 AND 664 THEN reflectance * .5
            ELSE  reflectance * .25 
       END AS 'REFLECTANCE'
FROM del 
WHERE wavelength BETWEEN 341 AND 348 
   OR wavelength BETWEEN 551 AND 664  
   OR wavelength BETWEEN 998 AND 1021
```

or a common select:

```
SELECT wavelength, 
       CASE WHEN (wavelength BETWEEN 341 AND 348) 
              OR (wavelength BETWEEN 998 AND 1021) THEN reflectance * .25 
            WHEN wavelength BETWEEN 551 AND 664 THEN reflectance * .5
            ELSE 1 ---(PUT YOUR DEFAULT) 
       END AS 'REFLECTANCE'
FROM del
```